# pom.xml not deploying to artifactory in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, gradle, artifactory

I am using Jenkins Artifactory plugin to deploy to an artifactory repository in my Gradle build. Since I need transitive dependency support for my artifact I need to deploy both jar and also pom.xml to artifactory.

Here is how my build.gradle looks like:

```
group 'com.group.name'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    // All of my dependencies
}

task writeNewPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            inceptionYear '2014'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("build/poms/pom-default.xml")
}
```

And here is my Jenkins Config for artifactory:

Maven3-artifactory integration is checked.

[image]

And I am running this gradle tasks in my build job:
**clean build writeNewPom**

I am using writeNewPom task in order to create pom.xml

Problem is that only jar file is deployed but pom.xml is not being deployed to artifactory.
I tried using "include pattern" and setting is as `build/libs/*.jar , build/poms/*.xml` but this way even jar is not deployed.